# Initial value of the conditional variance in the GARCH process

Tags: time-series, estimation, garch

From what I know, the GARCH(p,q) model is estimated via MLE and through an iterative process.  Let's say if i wanted to recreate a GARCH(1,1) parameter estimation with excel solver (through maximizing the log-likelihood), how are my initial GARCH terms $ \sigma_t^2$ set?

More specifically, given $ \epsilon_t = v_t\sqrt{\sigma_t^2}$ where $$\sigma_t^2 = \alpha_0 +\alpha_1\epsilon^2_{t-1}+\alpha_2\sigma_{t-1}^2 $$
how does the process of parameter estimation start since we do not know what $\sigma_{t-1}$ is?

One answer I've read from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113294/does-garchp-0-make-sense-at-all/113303#113303) shows that the program set the initial GARCH term to be the sample variance or its expected value.  Is this how we approach it?

Comment: It may depend on the particular software you want to mimic; but sample variance sounds like a good choice in general.

Comment: Let's say it is Matlab, with matlab, i fit the Garch model on the same data set with the estimate() function.  Then I inferred the residuals through infer(estmdl, x) and found my fitted model through fitted = y-residuals;  On a graph, the estimation was almost spot on.  However when I transfer this over to the excel solver, I end up with an almost identical loglikelihood but very different results.  I am taking the Loglikelihood function from here: http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~yiyang/research/computational_finance/Parameter_Estimation_of_GARCH_Model.pdf

Answer (score 6):

I know of at least five ways of initializing the volatility process:

1) Set it equal to $\varepsilon_{t-1}^2$,

2) The sample variance,

3) Unconditional variance of the model ($\alpha_0/(1-\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)$),

4) Allow it it to be an parameter to be estimated,

5) Backcasting with an exponential filter.

The topic is discussed in further detail [here](http://www2.mate.polimi.it/ocs/viewpaper.php?id=127&cf=7)

Comment: The link from [@Johan Stax Jakobsen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/174042/johan-stax-jakobsen) is now dead. I believe the paper referenced is the following: Pelagatti, Matteo, and Francesco Lisi. "Variance initialisation in GARCH estimation." S. Co. 2009. Sixth Conference. Complex Data Modeling and Computationally Intensive Statistical Methods for Estimation and Prediction. Maggioli Editore, 2009.