# Inaccuracies due to initial values in GARCH(1, 1) simulation

Tags: time-series, arima, monte-carlo, garch, kurtosis

I'm experimenting with non-normal innovations standard GARCH(1, 1) model
$$\epsilon_t = \sqrt h_t z_t$$
$$h_t = \omega + \alpha \epsilon_{t-1} + \beta h_{t-1}$$
Where $E[z_t] = 0$, $E[z_t^2] = 1$, but $z_t$ could be non-normal.

I've worked through Bai, Russell, and Tiao's 2003 paper "Kurtosis of GARCH and stochastic volatility models with non-normal innovations", which provides a helpful theorem (2.1) on the various moments of the variables in the GARCH process. I took the time to verify these results on my own, so I'm fairly sure they're correct.

To test the moments, I generate an ensemble of 200,000 samples, where each sample is an array of $N$ realizations of $\epsilon$. So I end up with a 200,000 by $N$ array. This allows me to quickly compare various sample moments with their theoretical values. For example, I can take the mean of a column, which should be near the theoretical $E[e_t] = 0$. This in particular works without issues.

However, on some of the moments, something is happening that I can't formally explain. For example, consider the first autocovariance of the squared realizations
$$\gamma_1 = E[(\epsilon_t^2 - \mu)(\epsilon_{t-1}^2 - \mu)]$$
where I've defined $\mu = \omega / (1 - \phi)$, and $\phi = \alpha + \beta$. By using the ARMA representation of $\epsilon_t^2$ (eq 2 in Bai et al) along with some tricks from Chapter 3 of Hamilton's "Time Series Analysis" (his 3.3.18 in particular), I was able to derive:
$$\gamma_1 = \alpha \frac{1 - \phi^2 + \alpha \phi}{1 - \phi^2} Var(u_t)$$ where $u_t = \epsilon_t^2 - h_t$. Since I used this result later to derive Bai et al's (15), I'm pretty confident it's correct.

But when I check this via simulation, comparing the sample covariance of adjacent columns to this theoretical $\gamma_1$, I only get an approximately correct result if I calculate the sample covariance among the last few columns of the array. If I instead use some of the first few columns, the sample covariance can be less than half of the value of the theoretical $\gamma_1$.

I suspect this has to do with how I'm initializing the simulation. Following [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133286/initial-value-of-the-conditional-variance-in-the-garch-process), I'm setting the initial value of $h$ to be $\mu$, its unconditional expectation. I wonder if there's a more informed choice I can make, unfortunately, literature seems to be quite sparse on this topic. In "Small sample properties of GARCH estimates and persistence", Hwang and Pereira simulate a GARCH. They mention that "the first 1000 observations are not used to avoid any problems from initial values". But what are these problems, formally? Is there any way I can avoid having to generate 1000 extra samples, only to discard them?

Comment: Interesting. Could you share a minimal reproducible example of your simulation (the part that goes wrong)? Also, $\mu$ is an unfortunate symbol for denoting the unconditional variance. The latter is usually denoted by $\sigma^2$, while the former usually denotes the expected value of the original time series.

Comment: The simulation doesn't seem to be wrong, per se, so I'm not sure what code I could send. I'm just iterating on the GARCH(1, 1) definition, making use of numpy broadcasting to get my 200,000 x N array. If I generate a bunch of "dummy" observations, all sample moments end up agreeing with their theoretical values. For example, for (w, a, B) = (.01, .03, .95), theoretical gamma_1 = .0737. The sample covariance of the LAST two columns of the array is also .0737. But if I take the sample covariance of the FIRST two columns, I get .03. Seems to be "problems from initial values"

Comment: OK, I see. I will be looking forward to an answer.