# ARCH: How is Volatility Formulation rewritten as Residuals Formulation

Tags: time-series, variance, residuals, garch, volatility

I am trying to understand the concept of ARCH(1) model from [this tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Li95a2biFCU&t=4m15s).
From 4:15, it's explained that,
the variance of residuals **(1)** can be formulated as **(2)**.
([image: equation] = residual at *t*, [image: equation]=variance of residual(volatility) at *t*, *w*=white noise)

[image: equation]   **(1)**

[image: equation] **(2)**

However, as [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH) says,

> ARCH model ... describes the variance of the current error term or innovation as a function of the actual sizes of **the previous time periods' error terms**

and the variance of residuals can be written as **(3)**.

[image: equation] **(3)**

---

I am very confused because what wiki says seems to contradict with what's explained in the said video.
**(1)** seems to correspond with the fact that [**ARCH model takes into account the previous volatility(variance of residuals)**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inoBpq1UEn4&t=9m49s).
**(3)** seems to correspond with the fact that **[ARCH model takes into account the previous time period's error terms (residuals)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH)**.

Could anyone clarify how the **(1)** is re-formulated to **(2)** mathematically?
Also please tell me if there's anything that I seem to misunderstand.

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement in the first video appears to be wrong. In particular, **(1)** is wrong while **(2)** is correct. **(3)** is also correct, and it agrees with **(2)**. The second video regarding **(1)** is not wrong, but the relationship is more subtle than indicated by **(1)**.

To see what happens if one tries to use **(1)** instead of **(2)**, look at the graph in my answer in the tread ["Does GARCH($p$,0) make sense at all?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113294).

Generally, if you are unsure about a video, it may be a good idea to cross check with a respectable textbook. That could be Hamilton "Time Series Analysis", Tsay "Analysis of Financial Time Series", Zivot "Modeling Financial Time Series with S-PLUS" or some other one.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing up my confusion! Could you elaborate a bit more on what you said "the relationship is more subtle than indicated by **(1)**"?
Because to me, **(2)** does not seem to take into account the volatility, but the previous time period's error.

Comment: @koyamashinji, previous time period's error comes from a distribution that has some variance, and that variance is $\sigma_{t-1}^2$. So $\sigma_{t-1}^2$ is there but only indirectly, i.e. through the realization $\varepsilon_{t-1}$. In other words, $\varepsilon_{t-1}$ comes from a distribution the variance of which is $\sigma_{t-1}^2$.